# How to get the input value of a checkbox (true/false)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have this html and I am trying to get the input value of a certain checkbox

```
    var option = document.createElement('li');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    var optionId = "option" + "" + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
    var checkBoxId = "checkbox" + "" + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
    var labelId = "label" + "" + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
    var labelname = "name" + "" + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    label.id = labelId;
    label.name= labelname;
    option.id = optionId;
    option.className = "optionName";
    checkbox.id = checkBoxId;
    checkBoxId.htmlFor = option;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Option ' + subquestionNumber));
    option.appendChild(label); //add `label` to `li`
    option.appendChild(checkbox); //add `checkbox` to `li`
    q.appendChild(option);

    var checkboxes = document.querySelector(labelId);
    document.getElementById("testingBox6").innerHTML = checkboxes;
```

I want to save the input value to the variable checkboxes

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

With `Jquery`, it can be simple. But, you can try this without `Jquery`

> document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked;

Comment: I get this error when I try Hai's suggestion. checkboxId is not defined

Comment: Nevermid, thank you it worked. The checkBox was written like this. Thank you

Comment: `checkboxId` follow your code on above question. I follow that. You can replace a particaly ID `document.getElementById('your-checkbox-id').checked;`

Answer (score 1):

you can get true/false with `checked`

for example

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", ()=> {
   console.log(checkbox.checked); // it gives true or false when you clicked
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even you can use

```
document.querySelector('#checkBoxId').checked;
```